# Json строку с csrf токеном распарсить в массив в php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, yii2

На сервере при помощи аякса получаю json строку вида:

```
[
    {
        "original_name":"Penguins.jpg",
        "serverurl":"upload/images/51528167ef67370933c5b95eed605d60.jpg"
    },    
    {
        "original_name":"Tulips.jpg",
        "serverurl":"upload/images/216f59417d2a304a1e5604ec070007fa.jpg"
    }
]
_csrf=Y1FxYVNpUnckF‌​R45PSViEAtnABkZUGUmC‌​SIGCBRROkQUOUAuAFEaI‌​g==" –
```

как избавиться от csrf токена и распарсить строку в массив?

Comment: Раз это нужно сделать на стороне сервера, покажите необходимый участок кода

Answer (score 1):

Обрезать строку:

```
var str = '[ { "original_name":"Penguins.jpg", "serverurl":"upload/images/51528167ef67370933c5b95eed605d60.jpg" }, { "original_name":"Tulips.jpg", "serverurl":"upload/images/216f59417d2a304a1e5604ec070007fa.jpg" } ]_csrf=Y1FxYVNpUnckF‌​R45PSViEAtnABkZUGUmC‌​SIGCBRROkQUOUAuAFEaI‌​g==';
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('_csrf'));
```

Спарсить строку в объект при помощи jQuery:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(str);
```

Comment: мне надо это сделать на серверной стороне с помощью php